# DataTables apply column formatting to filter also

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, formatting, dt

When creating a `datatable` with `filter = 'top'` and also using a formatting function on a column, the formatting isn't applied to the filter control for that column. Is there a way to format the filter controls as well?

For example, if I have floating-point numbers formatted as a percentage, the slider in the filter still shows floating point numbers.

```
library(DT)

my_data <- mtcars
my_data$wt_pctile <- trunc(rank(my_data$wt)) / length(my_data$wt)

datatable(my_data,
          filter = 'top') %>%
  formatPercentage('wt_pctile')
```

[image: Percent filter range is not formatted as percentage]

Comment: Hey Brian. Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm having the exact same.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is this:

1. use the earlier trick to show the values as % (multiply by 100 and use `formatCurrency`
2. use CSS and the `:after` pseudoclass to append a "%" after the filter values

the solution will look like this
[image: final app]

The full code for the app is this:

```
data <- ggplot2::mpg[, c("manufacturer", "model", "year", "cty")]
data$cty_perc <- data$cty / max(data$cty)

shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = shiny::fluidPage(
    shiny::tags$style('td[data-type="number"] div + div span:after { content: "%" !important; }'),
    shiny::h1("Styled Table"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      dd <- data
      dd$cty_perc <- round(dd$cty_perc * 100, 2)
      
      DT::datatable(dd, filter = "top") |>
        DT::formatCurrency("cty_perc", digits = 2, currency = "%", before = FALSE)
    })
  }
)
```

The only downside of this is that it adds percentages to all numeric columns (not that cty is of type integer and not numeric!).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a way to do it. A workaround can be multiplying by 100:

```
my_data$wt_pctile <- my_data$wt_pctile * 100
```

And than displaying as a string with the % sign:

```
datatable(my_data, filter = 'top') %>%
  formatString(suffix = "%",columns = "wt_pctile")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Yanir is halfway there! What if you multiplied by 100 and then

```
datatable(my_data, filter = 'top') %>%
  formatCurrency(columns = "wt_pctile", 
  currency = "%", 
  before = FALSE)
```

This prevents double or triple %s when sorting.