# Implementing a dynamic slider to update DT table percentage

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

Hi The given code generates a basic table using DT representing list of letters and percentages. I wish to add a slider within the DT tables, such that when I place the slider on specific percentage, I get the rows corresponding to that percentage and below. Thanks and please help.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
library(scales)
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Basic datatable"),
# Create a new row for the table.
fluidRow(
DT::dataTableOutput("table")
) 
)
server <- function(input, output) {
# Filter data based on selections
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
a = percent(1:10)
b = c("aa","bbb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg","ff","gg","hh")

data1 = data.frame(a,b)
data1

}))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to implement `sliderInput` and dynamically change the `datatable` in `server`. There are other ways to control the `datatable` dynamically, but I am posting this code to match your exact requirement.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

a <- percent(1:10)
b <- c("aa","bbb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg","ff","gg","hh")
data1 <- data.frame(a,b)
a_temp <- as.numeric(gsub("%|,", "", a))      #Removing % and , from the data frame
data1_temp <- data.frame(a_temp,b)            #New data frame with integer values to reference row number required later

if(interactive()){
  shinyApp(
    ui <- fluidPage(

      titlePanel("Basic datatable"),

      sliderInput("slider1", "Choose Range of Percentage", 
                  min = a_temp[1], 
                  max = a_temp[10],
                  value = c(a_temp[1], a_temp[10]),
                  step = 100
                  ),

      fluidRow(
        DT::dataTableOutput("table")
      ) 
    ),

    server = function(input, output){

      minRowVal <- reactive({
        which(grepl(input$slider1[[1]], data1_temp$a))        #Retrieve row number that matches selected range on sliderInput
      })

      maxRowVal <- reactive({
        which(grepl(input$slider1[[2]], data1_temp$a))        #Retrieve row number that matches selected range on sliderInput
      })

      observeEvent(input$slider1, {
        output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
          data1[minRowVal():maxRowVal(), ]
        })
      })

    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sagar, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46532497/datatables-apply-column-formatting-to-filter-also).

```
library(DT)

DT::datatable(
  data.frame(
    a = 1:10/100,
    b = letters[1:10]
  ),
  filter = "top"
) %>% formatPercentage('a')
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gregor, very helpful.